# Distributed python

Tags: python, distributed

What is the best python framework to create distributed applications? For example to build a P2P app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could checkout [pyprocessing](http://pyprocessing.berlios.de/) which will be included in the standard library as of 2.6. It allows you to run tasks on multiple processes using an API similar to threading.

Answer (score 9):

I think you mean "Networked Apps"? Distributed means an app that can split its workload among multiple worker clients over the network.

You probably want.
[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).  There is a P2P framework for Twisted called "[Vertex](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodVertex)".  While not actively maintained, it does allow you to tunnel through NATs and make connections directly between users in a very abstract way; if there were more interest in this sort of thing I'm sure it would be more actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the source of BitTorrent for starters and see how they did it.

http://download.bittorrent.com/dl/

Answer (score 1):

If it's something where you're going to need tons of threads and need better concurrent performance, check out [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/). Otherwise you could just use the [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) protocols. In response to Ben's post, if you don't want to look over the BitTorrent source, you could just look at the article on [the BitTorrent protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)).